# How do I make a sol class, accessible in Lua, have immutable methods?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-sol

I currently have this simple code adapted from one of [Sol's examples](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/blob/develop/examples/source/overridable_function_members.cpp):

```cpp
#define SOL_ALL_SAFETIES_ON 1
#include "lua/sol.hpp"

#include <iostream>

struct Object 
{
    Object() {}

    void mutable() 
    {
        std::cout << "mutable method called\n";
    }

    void immutable()
    {
        std::cout << "immutable method called\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    sol::state lua;
    lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);

    auto object = lua.new_usertype<Object>("object", sol::constructors<Object()>());

    object["mutable"] = &Object::mutable;
    object["immutable"] = &Object::immutable;

    sol::string_view code = R"(
        -- I want this one to throw an error like 'can't change immutable method'
        function object:immutable()
            print("Changed")
        end 
        
        function object:mutable() 
            print("Also changed") 
        end
        
        obj = object.new()

        obj:immutable();
        obj:mutable();
    )";

    sol::protected_function_result result = lua.safe_script(code, &sol::script_pass_on_error);

    if (not result.valid())
    {
        sol::error error = result;
        std::cout << error.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

In this example, the C++ `Object` class has two methods:

- `immutable` which is a method that I **don't** want to be changeable in Lua;
- `mutable` which is a method that I want to be changeable.

So I'm trying to make changing the function `immutable` **impossible** in Lua.

Since I'm using sol2 (v 3.3.0) for making the process of integrating Lua simpler, I tried to integrate [another example from its documentation](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/readonly.html?highlight=readonly#id1).
But I was unable to adapt it since I'm not an expert in Lua and this example was using tables and not the C++ class wrapper (`usertype`).

I also tried to use Sol's `readonly` property which has been utilized in the first example to make *variables* immutable by doing:

```cpp
object["final"] = sol::readonly(&Object::final);
```

But the last time I tried, it gave me some access errors even when I was only calling the function, but now it just does nothing.

Does anyone know how to make only certain members of a C++ class immutable inside Lua scripts/states?

Comment: I've not done anything like this in Lua, but I believe you need to make the `final()` method [*immutable*](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ImmutableObjects) in Lua.

Comment: I read the documentation you provided but I couldn't come up on how to achieve the examples on the site with a c++ class